# React - issue with initialValues ant design when using referenced component

Tags: reactjs, antd

Using ant design input and forms, I am having trouble using `intialValues` when a component is referenced in. In this case, I am trying to pass in CustomInput.js, a ant design Input, into my form as `<Component/>`. Everything works except the initialValues.

Any ideas what to do to make `intialValues` work?

https://codesandbox.io/s/initialvalues-forked-keftp?file=/index.js:382-414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the props from your custom component down to `Input`, specifically the `value` prop:

```js
function CustomInput(
  { field, value = "", onChange = (e) => {}, disabled, ...rest },
  ref
) {
  return (
    <Input
      ref={ref}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      disabled={disabled}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/initialvalues-with-ref-forked-k8g6n?file=/customInput.js)

**Note:** I'm unsure as to what your `field` prop is. Since it's not a supported prop as part of the component's API, I left it out.